# PCL undefined reference to boost

Tags: pcl, boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I'm currently using Ubuntu 11.04 and install ROS via the source code method. I'm new and tried to play around with the erratic_robot example. When trying to do a rosmake, I came across a perception_pcl problem when compiling, the pcl folder in particular. Heres a snippet of the build_output.log:

/home/walter/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/io:
../libpcl_io.so.1.1.1: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()' ../libpcl_io.so.1.1.1: undefined reference to` boost::filesystem3::detail::status(boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
../libpcl_io.so.1.1.1: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[3]: *** [io/tools/convert_pcd_ascii_binary] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/walter/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
make[2]: *** [io/tools/CMakeFiles/convert_pcd_ascii_binary.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/walter/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build' make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/walter/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
make: *** [installed] Error 2

Any ideas? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12129/pcl-undefined-reference-to-boost/) by [WW](https://answers.ros.org/users/1455/ww/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Pls check the version of the boost library in your system. It has to be >= 1.46.1.

Hope this helps,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WW](https://answers.ros.org/users/1455/ww/) on 2011-11-29**:
Thanks for the response. ROS electric is set to use boost 1.42 (part of rosdep.yaml). I've installed boost 1.48 manually, however I don't know how to set ROS to use 1.48. It seems I should modify the rosdep.yaml file however I can't figure out how to do it correctly in the proper format.
Thanks,
WW

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-01**:
You just have to compile everything from source after upgrading boost.